# my calculator with javascript isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm trying to make a calculator with javascript but it's not working I don't understand where is the problem I still haven't finished it yet but still it is supposed to be able to take the numbers that I click but it doesn't

this is my javascript code

```js
class calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    this.operation = undefined
  }

  delete()

  appendNumber(number) {
    this.currentOperand = number
  }

  chooseOperation(operation)

  compute()

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand
  }
}

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]');
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');

const calculator = new calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Gothic A1', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00AAFF, #00FF6c);
}

.calc-grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}

.calc-grid>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

.calc-grid>button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

.span-two {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.output {
  grid-column: span 4;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.output .prev-op {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.output .curr-op {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>calaculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gothic+A1:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="calc-grid">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="prev-op"></div>
      <div data-current-operand class="curr-op"></div>
    </div>

    <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
    <button data-delete>DEL</button>
    <button data-operation>÷</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operation>X</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operation>+</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operation>-</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
  </div>

  <script src="home.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

can someone tell me why my code isn't working with a brief explanation

Comment: Well are there error messages in the console?

Comment: `const calculator = new calculator` <-- why is your variable and class named the same thing? Typically we define classes with a capital letter. `class Calculator {}` and `const calculator = new Calculator()`

Comment: Your bug is also related to the fact you have `delete()` and  `chooseOperation(operation)` and `compute()` in your class. Where are the brackets?

Comment: For sure your javascript is incomplete and full of bugs (as @epascarello has pointed out a few of the bugs, and you also mentioned that it is not yet completed ) . Please note that javascript usually will NOT run further if it encounters a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. functions like `compute` should have {} even though they are empty. Add {} to  all functions without {}.
   Example: `compute(){}`
2. you are reusing variable name "calculator", which is used by a class also defined as "calculator". This is causing error, so you need to change variable's name to something else.